# Why are include paths unseen when #include in Android NDK code?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, include-path

I want to add an include path to my Android NDK project but the included files are not found by the compiler. I double checked that the included files exist on my system. What am I doing wrong here?

Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-write-strings
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +:= $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_CFLAGS +:= -O3 
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS +:=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I/absolute/path/to/my/include //--->here the include path is set
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog -lc

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Included headers in jni/hello-jni.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
#include <codecs/codecs.h>
#include <test/test.h>
#include <mymath/mymath.h>
}
....
```

Error log:

```
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:34: fatal error: codecs/codecs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Maybe try `ndk build V=1` and see what the gcc command line actually looks like?  Are you sure you have the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS +:=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
```

Using `+:=` here means that the value of LOCAL_CFLAGS used is that at the time of the declaration of LOCAL_CPPFLAGS. At this point LOCAL_CFLAGS has not been set (it is set on the next line). Try changing it to:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS +=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
```

This will evaluate LOCAL_CPPFLAGS every time it is used and will pick up the right value. Alternatively, declare LOCAL_CFLAGS before you use it in LOCAL_CPPFLAGS.

Comment: There is no need to copy `LOCAL_CFLAGS` to `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`. NDK uses `LOCAL_CFLAGS` for both C and C++bu sources. Don't confuse them with `LOCAL_CONLYFLAGS`.

Comment: @AlexCohn well I just thought the `+:=` looked odd, it's something you don't see in make very often. I didn't check the NDK docs until now. They say prefer `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` over `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I...`. The only niggle is that LOCAL_C_INCLUDES may not allow an absolute path, the docs are unclear (they say "list of paths relative to the NDK root dir"). But the `CFLAGS` var should be added to `CPPFLAGS` anyway by the ndk build system, maybe using +:= screwed that up.

Comment: _No_, `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` accept absolute paths beautifully. They are directly translated into `-Ithis -Ithat` without path manipulation (unlike the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`). And _no_, LOCAL_CFLAGS effects both C and C++ compilation. There is a special (and relatively recent) addition of `CONLYFLAGS` which behave more like the usual `CFLAGS` for GNU make.

Answer (score 1):

Try add your headers in LOCAL_C_INCLUDES

Answer (score 1):

Your **Android.mk** does not follow the basic rules. Let's try the rewrite:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE     := hello-jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -Wno-write-strings
ifneq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
  LOCAL_CFLAGS   += -O3 
endif
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /absolute/path/to/my/include 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := hello-jni.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -ldl -llog -lc

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This assumes that you have files `/absolute/path/to/my/include/codecs/codecs.h` etc. or `<project>/jni/codecs/codecs.h`. If your project also has `jni/test/test.h` and `jni/mymath/mymath.h`, you probably don't need the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` defined at all. `jni` directory will be used automatically